# how can I create a menu screen for my spritekit game?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, menu, sprite-kit

I already put my actual Gamescene inside the MyScene class. How can I create a menu screen even If I already put the game in the MyScene class. I tried to include the menu before the actual gamescene but that didnt work

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]){
        SKSpriteNode *startButton = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"startButton"];
        startButton.position = CGPointMake(160, 300);
        startButton.size = CGSizeMake(200, 200);
        startButton.name = @"startButton";
        [self addChild:startButton];
    }
    return self;
    /* Setup your scene here */
    self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
    //SKSpriteNode *bgImage = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@""];
    //[self addChild:bgImage];
    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.171875 green:0.2421875 blue:0.3125 alpha:1.0];


    world = [SKNode node];
    [self addChild:world];

    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;

    generator = [SPWorldGenerator generatorWithWorld:world];
    [self addChild:generator];
    [generator populate];


    hero = [SPHero hero];
    [world addChild:hero];

    [self loadScoreLabels];

    cloud1 = [SPHero cloud1];
    [world addChild:cloud1];

    cloud2 = [SPHero cloud2];
    [world addChild:cloud2];

    cloud3 = [SPHero cloud3];
    [world addChild:cloud3];

    cloud4 = [SPHero cloud4];
    [world addChild:cloud4];
    //uihui//

    SKLabelNode *tapToBeginLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:GAME_FONT];
    tapToBeginLabel.name = @"tapToBeginLabel";
    tapToBeginLabel.text = @"tap to begin";
    tapToBeginLabel.fontSize = 20.0;
    [self addChild:tapToBeginLabel];
    [self animateWithPulse:tapToBeginLabel]; // ** GETS RESET LABEL PULSING ** //

    // ** PULSING TEXT ** //
    SKAction *disappear = [SKAction fadeAlphaTo:0.0 duration:0.6];
    SKAction *appear = [SKAction fadeAlphaTo:1.0 duration:0.6];
    SKAction *pulse = [SKAction sequence:@[disappear, appear]];
    [tapToBeginLabel runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:pulse]];
    // ** PULSING TEXT ** //


}

return self;
}


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"startButton"]) {

    SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition doorsOpenVerticalWithDuration:1.0];

    MyScene *game = [[MyScene alloc] initWithSize: CGSizeMake(self.size.width, self.size.height)];

    [self.scene.view presentScene:game transition:transition];
}
}
```

Comment: you can make another scene for your menu.  Or you can create a menu using a UIViewController

Comment: How would I go about doing that with my code above?Thank you so much.

Comment: read this tutorial, it will teach you how to transition between scenes
http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/working-with-scenes-in-sprite-kit

Comment: Thank You. But I dont think this tutorial shows me how to decide in which order to load my scenes. Whenever I run the application, the MyScene always loads first. How would I make the MenuScene be the first thing it loads up when ran?

Comment: go to your GameViewController, and look where MyScene is loaded.  Instead of loading MyScene.. Load MenuScene

Comment: Yes! But when I ran the code, it worked fine, except when I clicked to transition, the game froze and gave me a thread breakpoint error in my method where I centered the camera on node. Just to be clear, I am sure that i didnt create the breakpoint myself.

Comment: You probably need to create a new question with specific code just pertaining to that question.  Try to fix things yourself.  if you get stuck on one particular area, post the relevant code.  This site is meant to help people figure things out when they get stuck on a specific problem.